# 16bit Real Mode C Compiler for Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, compiler-construction, 16-bit, real-mode

I am looking for a C compiler that runs on mac and it needs to compile to 8086 16 bit real mode machine code.

Comment: What kind of platform are you targeting exactly

Comment: I'm building my own OS and I want to write the kernel in C rather than using assembly all the time

Comment: And you want to run it in 16-bit mode?

Comment: Yep I want the entire thing to be in 16bit real mode :) (it's more a proof of concept than anything)

Comment: Why? I hope you realize programming 16 bit real mode is a lot more painful than programming for 32 bit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [Borland's Turbo C](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20841) inside [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) or something like that. That way you can actually run whatever you compile.

I've run some antique 16 bit DOS code under it and it works flawlessly.